# HTTPS on OpenCart - How to disable HTTPS on /admin?

Tags: .htaccess, https, opencart

Got a website that need to use HTTPS in the frontend, but the HTTPS is causing issues on OpenCart /admin login page. Seems like all styles are disabled when accessing the /admin section through HTTPS. Client wants everyone to access the site through HTTPS, so we have a 301 redirect to the HTTPS version of the site, but this is causing issues with /admin.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If your certificate is valid, this shouldn't be an issue in the `/admin`
My guess is your cert is for `yoursite.com` and your admin is forcing `www` to `www.yoursite.com` (possibly the other way around). Ensure you have the correct URL in your `/admin/config.php` for the certificate, particularly the `HTTPS_SERVER` value defined in there. If that doesn't fix it, you'll need to provide a link

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin folder. First Backup config.php Then edit config.php . Make **http://** url to **https://** .Then save . Now visit admin page , https works without no issue .